# Any simple method to run an interactive Python script on boot on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interactive, reboot, termios

I'm programming a string of LED matrix panels with a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Lite in Python, and the user needs to select which program they would like to run (scroll news feed, stock prices, weather, etc.). My plan is to have a wireless number pad hooked up to the Pi, where the arrow keys can be used to select a script. I already have this entire process working perfectly; however, I keep running into problems when scheduling the script to run on boot.

I've tried using rc.local, systemd, and crontab, but I usually run into the same error: `termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')` I'm guessing that the methods I've been using for running scripts at startup are only meant for daemons with no user interaction, and so there is no standard input set up. There is a login screen on startup, so maybe the keyboard is dedicated to that instead of my program. Is there any simple way to run an interactive script on startup without needing to login or type anything beforehand?

I replicated the problem with a shorter script that only deals with the input parts of my program (I took most of the below code from a blog post online, I'm a noob at this stuff). Again, this works fine when I run it manually but I can't get it working on boot. The error occurs on the line `oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)` for me:

```
import os
import termios
import fcntl
import select

fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)
oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
        inp, outp, err = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
        c = sys.stdin.read()
        print('Key pressed: ' + c)
```

Comment: Do you want to run in the startup?

Comment: Regular FIFOs (like those connecting stdout of a service to journald) _aren't_ terminals, so terminal-only ioctl don't work with them; similarly, `/dev/stdin` for a service is by default just `/dev/null`, which again is not a terminal and can't honor terminal-only ioctls. Anyhow -- what display device do you have connected to your RPi? What _is_ your `/dev/console`? Alternately, if you have a 
 meaningful `/dev/tty1` (which again depends on your hardware and kernel parameters), just open and use it instead of `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout`.

Comment: Mind, you _can_ configure systemd to give a service a connection direct to the terminal, but you don't get that with the default configuration; you need to go out of your way to set the service up for it. And I'd suggest just disabling the systemd tty instance for whichever tty you use for your program.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your reply! To answer your first question, I'm using a monitor to see my output while I'm testing. My `/dev/console` seems to be connected to `/dev/tty1`, the correct way to check is with the `tty` command right? I'm intrigued by your second comment; systemd was giving me the most trouble but connecting directly to a terminal sounds perfect.

Comment: @Suman Yes. But it doesn't need to run _in_ the startup per se, I'm fine with it running directly _after_ the boot sequence if needed.

Comment: @glitchdemall can we connect to teamviwer or anydesk to better understand

Comment: @glitchdemall, see `StandardInput=tty-force` in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html; you may want `StandardOutput=tty` as well. I'm pretty sure that's already documented in an answer elsewhere in the Stack Exchange network, but am not sure if that was here (in which case the question could be closed as duplicate if the same solution indeed fixes your problem) or on [unix.se].

Comment: Hello ... are you using pipenv or the like... maybe have a shell script that does the necessary pipenv/python setup and have that run ... unless you already tried that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Perfect, this worked! When I first tried this out, the login screen kept appearing and causing problems in fetching input. I added the line `Conflicts=getty@tty1.service` into my service file and that did the trick. Thanks for all the help, and yeah my question does seem to be a duplicate of [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103616/boot-into-text-console-and-auto-run-script) post I found when researching your answer.